# How do I select the style of a lowercase gamma?

Tags: fonts, symbols, greek

It is traditional in Physics to use a lowercase gamma that looks like a Y. Without going into the question of whether that tradition is wrong, how do I differentiate in math mode Latex markup between a Gamma that looks like a Y and a Gamma with a loop?

No, I do not mean either capital or upright.

I'd prefer avoiding Unicode unless ArXiV now supports xetex.

I don't know how to insert the PDF as an image, but http://mason.gmu.edu/~smetz3/humor/dirac.pdf is generated from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=10in,top=0.75in, bottom=0in,   left=0in, right=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\vspace{.5in}

\begin{center}
{\Huge \bfseries Which part of}
\end{center}

\vspace{1.75in}

{\Huge
  \[
    \bm{(\gamma^{\mu } (i\hbar \partial _{\mu } - {\frac {e}{c}}A_{\mu })-mc) \psi =0}
  \]
}

\vspace{1.75in}

\begin{center}
{\Huge \bfseries don't you understand?}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is a "gamma with a loop"?

Comment: Do you mean `\gammaup`? This is mainly a matter of the used font

Comment: I think you try to distinguish btw. a small gamma (γ) and a capital one (Γ), which would be \gamma and \Gamma respectively.

Comment: @StefanSchroeder: there is no loop in `\Gamma` ....

Comment: haha, sure, but perhaps the question was just inaccurate. It's just a comment, mind you.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23871/grabbing-a-single-greek-glyph-from-an-alternative-font-in-math-mode

Comment: Are you tied to any particular (math) font family, or are you free to choose whichever math font pleases your eye?

Comment: You might also try any of these: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html

Comment: You can also use [LGR-encoded text fonts](https://ctan.org/topic/font-greek) with `mathastext`.

Comment: Since people here are baffled at guessing what you are trying to get, why don't you post an image?

Comment: The PDF uses the Liberation fonts for text and OpenSymbol for math, as far as I can see. You didn't generate it with LaTeX.

Comment: This is LibreOffice not LaTeX, I'm not sure if these two fonts can be setup in LaTeX?

Answer (score 8):

Please choose one of these.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
tipa:    & \textbabygamma\\
upgreek: & $\upgamma$\\
tipa:    & \textgamma\\
tipa:    & \textramshorns\\
default: & $\gamma$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You made me at least smile a little.

Comment: The `isomath` package [has a pretty comprehensive list](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/isomath/isomath.pdf#table.3) of the OML math alphabets available. There are around 50, plus LGR fonts and fonts like AMS Euler and Fourier with unique encodings.

Answer (score 4):

### In the Modern Toolchain

`\usepackage{unicode-math}`, then check the [list of Unicode-math symbols](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf#f) for a font specimen of all the math symbols in a half-dozen Unicode math fonts.  Pick a font you like.

If you want to change only the Greek letters to another Unicode font, including any of the fonts on your desktop, add `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}`, as your default, then `\setmathfont[range=it/{Greek,greek}, Scale=MatchLowercase]{Artemisia}` (for example).

In general, write your new documents for the new toolchain if you can, and the legacy toolchain if you have to.

#### With Legacy Math Fonts

Load `isomath` and pick [one of the Greek alphabets it supports.](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/isomath/isomath.pdf#table.3)  This package and `mathalfa` give you the closest thing the NFSS ecosystem has to a standard interface for selecting the math alphabets of your choice.

#### With Legacy Greek Text Fonts

You can use [LGR-encoded legacy NFSS fonts](https://ctan.org/topic/font-greek) in math mode through `mathastext`.  This example loads GFS Bodoni:

```
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{gfsbodoni}
\usepackage[italic, LGRgreek, itgreek]{mathastext} % or upgreek, or upGreek.
```

If you want to write actual Greek words, also load `babel`.

#### If You Really Want Just that One Letter

Look up the encoding of the legacy font whose symbol you want, and declare it as a symbol alphabet. This example typesets the Euler-Mascheroni constant with the γ from the font AMS Euler, in ISO style.  The constant is unslanted, not italic, and I give it the *de facto* standard name `\upgamma`.  The other symbols are taken from `newpx`, a clone of Palatino, another font by Hermann Zapf that goes well with his AMS Euler.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{eulerup}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upgamma}{\mathord}{eulerup}{"0D}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\[ \upgamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(
      - \ln n + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
   \right) \]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: The Euler Constant]

By the way, if you like this setup, here is how you get it with the modern toolchain (after downloading Khaled Hosny’s font Neo Euler from GitHub):

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
  Scale = 1.0 ,
  Ligatures = {Common, TeX} ]
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
% A good matching sans serif, should you want one, is Optima.  A free clone
% is URW Classico.
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
% Neo Euler by Khaled Hosny, based on AMS Euler by Hermann Zapf:
% https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek},
             script-style={},
             sscript-style={}]{Neo Euler}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{10cm}
\[ \upgamma = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(
      - \ln n + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
   \right) \]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I do not mean capital Gamma; I mean lower case Gamma in Math mode, with one of two styles: the more correct form with a loop and the more traditional form (in Physics) with a tail. I'm trying to avoid Unicode because ArXiV doesn't support XeTeX and I don't want to get into the habit of doing anything that won't work with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @shmuel: You can get a good help from the community here if you post an image.

Comment: @shmuel That makes sense. All of those solutions work for a lowercase gamma in math mode, and all but the first work in PDFLaTeX.

Comment: @AboAmmar What is the markup to render a block of TeX, and can I do it within a comment or only in the base message or an answer?

Comment: @Davislor I thought that symbols beginning with text were only for use in text mode. I only mentioned capital Gamma because of a comment by Stefan Schroeder; what I want is a lower case slanted Gamma.

Comment: @shmuel Right, `\textfoo` commands are, by convention, text-mode. I don’t use them in those examples, but you can use any text-mode command in math mode by wrapping it in `\mbox` or `\text` from `amsmath`.

Comment: @shmuel All those methods will produce a slanted gamma if you use them with a slanted font. The Euler example was just the least-contrived one I could think of to use the letter gamma from a non-OML, non-LGR, NFSS font. And it *was* the Euler constant.

Comment: @shmuel To get syntax highlighting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting However, the code will normally autodetect what language you’re writing in, based on the tags of your question.

Comment: @Davislor I wasn't looking for syntax highlighting. There are some environments where I can include LaTeX code in a message and it will be rendered as LaTeX rather than just prettyprinted. I suspect that the answer is to convert it to PNG and include that.

Comment: @shmuel Oh, you mean MathJax? Very similar to LaTeX, but not exactly the same. Some other sites on StackExchange support it. I generally try to insert the Unicode math characters.