# Get a proper double-struck one while using amsmath

Tags: math-mode, amssymb

I am using the `amssymb` package and from time to time I want to print a proper looking double-struck digit 1 as I could get by using the `bbold` package.

[image: The double-struck one I am looking for]

However they both are using the `\mathbb{}` command, so importing both just results in `bbold` overwriting the `amssymb` command (it somehow does not matter which package I import first). Since I only need a double-struck 1 and not any other double-struck number and I am using the `amssymb` version much more often, I thought of maybe declaring a new operator (e.g. `\id`) which uses the `bbold` version. I cannot seem to get it to work, however (Of course I also looked for other workarounds or other packages, but that did not turn out successfully either).

The somehow working version for at least defining my `\id` Operator looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbold}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{$\mathbb{1}$}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \id
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image: result]
Additionally, I get the following error massages:

> Undefined control sequence. (line 4)
> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. (line 4)
> Undefined control sequence. (line 11)

Comment: Please provide the error messages by copy-pasting them here (with formatting) instead of screenshots.

Comment: is this better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't working because (1) you don't load amsmath so `\DeclareMathOperator` is not defined, and (2) where you use `\id` you are already inside math mode because of the `\begin{equation}`, and so using the dollar signs `$` in the operator definition yields an error. That's not what `\DeclareMathOperator` is for anyway -- see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67506/newcommand-vs-declaremathoperator).  `\ensuremath` would have made more sense in your definition.

I take it the real problem is that you want to use the font loaded by amssymb for `\mathbb` as applied to letters, but loading the bbold package prevents that?

You can use the bbold font in math mode without loading the bbold package by declaring a math alphabet using a different name than `\mathbb`. (Look at `bbold.sty`--a slight variation of this is the only important command for math mode in it.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\bbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\id}{\ensuremath{\bbold{1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \id \mathbb{A}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: bbold examples]

There is a limit to how many math alphabets you're allowed to declare, so if you are at your limit because of other packages, you can modify the [instructions given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23882/411) for grabbing a single certain math mode symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\bboldsymbol[2][\mathord]{%
  #1{\@bboldmathsymbol{#2}}}
\def\@bboldmathsymbol#1{\mathchoice
  {\@bboldm@thsymbol{#1}\tf@size}
  {\@bboldm@thsymbol{#1}\tf@size}
  {\@bboldm@thsymbol{#1}\sf@size}
  {\@bboldm@thsymbol{#1}\ssf@size}}
\def\@bboldm@thsymbol#1#2{%
  \mbox{\fontsize{#2}{#2}\usefont{U}{bbold}{m}{n}#1}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\id}{\bboldsymbol{1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \id \mathbb{A}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```