# Greek characters in normal and sans serif math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, pdftex

Here's a simple demonstration program:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\DeclareMathVersion{sans}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{sl}

\begin{document}
\[
    x +  \alpha \beta
\]
\mathversion{sans}
\[
    x  + \alpha \beta
\]
\end{document}
```

It works fine, but the sans serif math does not have correct greek characters. Adding the following lines almost fixes the problem:

```
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\DeclareSymbolFont{grekletters}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{sl}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{grekletters}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{grekletters}{`b}
%...
\SetSymbolFont{grekletters}{sans}{LGR}{cmss}{m}{n}
```

But now the Greek characters in math mode are not the original ones. Where are the original ones?

There's a similar question:
[Replacing greek glyphs in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14996/replacing-greek-glyphs-in-math-mode). It is about luatex, though.

Also, I cannot use the `sansmath` package because it does not support my font encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `letters` font should be a font encoded as `OML`, not `OT1`; you can use CMBright for those and for the `OMS` family; a decent substitute for the large symbols can be Iwona:

```
\SetSymbolFont{operators}   {sans}{OT1}{cmss} {m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}     {sans}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{symbols}     {sans}{OMS}{cmbrs}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{sans}{OMX}{iwona}{m}{n}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `cmbr` and `cmbrm`? Anyway, it seems to work. Unfortunately the font does not end up vectorized in my final PDF.

Comment: The `omlcmbr.fd` file just refers to fonts defined in `omlcmbrm.fd`, so I used the latter. In my TeX Live I have the Type1 fonts, which are in a `hfbright` directory. What distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using Miktex 2.9. I guess I could live with the sans serif greek characters being bitmaps, but I'll leave this question open for a while to see if anyone else has an idea.

Comment: The MiKTeX packages page refers to `hfbright`: http://miktex.org/packages/hfbright

Comment: @Ben: Regarding the bitmap characters: I guess you have to install the CM-Super fonts. AFAIK they are not automatically installed even in a full MiKTeX installation because of the installation size.

Comment: @Speravir The CM-Super fonts have nothing to do with CM Bright. The description of the `hfbright` package for MiKTeX says: "The hfbright fonts (Type1 version of the CM Bright fonts)"